# Когда слышен шелест листьев и голоса птиц

Tags: согласование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как верно согласовать глагол, причастие или прилагательное с существительными?

Когда слышен (слышны) шелест листьев и голоса птиц.

Он немного пошатнул стоявший (стоявшие) рядом комод и шкаф.

В комнате стоял (стояли) старинный (старинные) диван, комод и шкаф.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет об отдельных предметах, то согласование по первому слову. А если одет о фразе, то можно и во множественном числе.

В комнате стоял стояли старинные: диван, комод и шкаф. (или тире)

В комнате стоял старинный диван,/ комод и шкаф. - однако тогда старинный будет относится только к дивану.

В комнате стоял диван,/ комод и шкаф.

Он немного пошатнул стоявшие рядом комод и шкаф. - пошатнул их вместе.

Он немного пошатал стоявший рядом комод и шкаф. - пошатал по отдельности, сначала один, потом второй.

Когда слышен шелест листьев и голоса птиц. - можно, - момент, когда слышен один и другой звуки. Хотя, такая фраза выглядит незавершенной.

Когда слышны шелест листьев и голоса птиц. - когда слышны звуки леса.

Он проснулся, когда уже был слышен шелест листьев/ и голоса птиц разносили во все концы весёлые трели.

Когда слышны шелест листьев и голоса птиц наступает утро и я просыпаюсь. - насчёт последнего не уверен, может нужны запятые.